# Playing a WAV file in Java using Java Media Framework

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

[image: The project in Eclipse]

[image: The Eclipse console output]

Why isn't it working ? I even tried to test if the clip is running, using **isRuning** method, the only thing I get is the file length and **False** as a return to **isRunning** method.

The **WAV** file I'm trying to play is from **Wikipedia**'s **WAV** file article, the second file on the formats table. I guess it's pretty well formatted.

Comment: Don't put images of textual information!  Copy/paste the **text**.  As an aside, the example code shown has *nothing* to do with JMF - it uses Java Sound.  See the comments in the **working** example in the [Java Sound info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) page for a hint as to why your attempt fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't really see your code, I'm posting how I do it, this code "loads" the sounds:

```
    AudioInputStream audioPush = null;

    try {
        push = AudioSystem.getClip();

        URL urlPush = getClass().getResource(
                    "path to the file");

        audioPush = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(urlPush);

        push.open(audioPush);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Then you have to play it like so:

```
push.start();
```

This is how I do it, dunno if there is another way, but this one works.